# Как сделать, чтобы текст номеров не съезжал, пока не кончится ширина материнского блока?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Контакты и карта помещены в разные материнские блоки, которым задано значение 
`with: 50%` каждому по отдельности.
При изменении ширины окна номера контактов преждевременно съезжают, хотя задумка, чтобы они всегда были в одну строку, а потом карта перемещается под блок с контактами.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как осуществить задуманное?

Видео проблемы: https://youtu.be/wllEjcGGWLE

```css
.container2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -o-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.div-title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}
.text-title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 4.5vh;
  font-family: Impact;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.main-div-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%
}
.main-div {
  width: 93%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: rgba(333, 333, 333, .5);
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 0.35vh solid black;
}
.text-part {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
.text-part-position {
  width: 61%;
  height: 84.5%;
  margin-top: 9vh;
  margin-left: 5vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.write.us {
  
}
.one {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2.40vh;
  font-family: impact, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.15vh;
}
.two p {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 1.6vh;
  line-height: 2.5vh;
  font-family: Courier New, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: left;
}
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
}
.first-number {
  display: inline-block;
}
.number {
  display: inline-block;

}
.e-mail-us {
  margin-top: 2vh;
}
.e-mail {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2.40vh;
  line-height: 2.5vh;
  font-family: impact, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.15vh;
}
.e-adress {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 1.6vh;
  line-height: 2.5vh;
  font-family: Courier New, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 1.5vh;
}
.adress {
  margin-top: 2vh;
}
.adress_title {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.9vh;
  line-height: 2.5vh;
  font-family: impact, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.15vh;
}
.adress_text p {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 1.45vh;
  line-height: 2.5vh;
  font-family: Courier New, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: left;
}
.map-div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
.map {
  width: 48.3vh;
  height: 45.8vh;
  border: 0.3vh black solid;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 6.4vh;
  margin-right: 4vh;
}
.pdng-lft_1 {
  padding-left: 1vh;  
}
```

```html
<main>
     <section>
      <div class="container2">
       <div class="div-title">
       <p class="text-title"> Наши контакты:</p>
      </div>
      <div class="main-div-container">
       <div class="main-div">
       <div class="text-part">
        <div class="text-part-position">
          <div class="write-us">
           <span class="one">
            Напишите или позвоните нам:<br>
           </span>
           <span class="two">
            <p class="pdng-lft_1">
             <span class="underline">Иерей Роман Клевцов</span>: <span class="first-number">+7-999-465-04-12</span> <br>
             <span class="underline">Матушка Нина</span>: <span class="number">+7-953-795-92-63</span>
            </p>
           </span>
          </div>
          <div class="e-mail-us"> 
           <span class="e-mail">
            E-mail:
            <div class="pdng-lft_1 e-adress" >
             klevcovra@mail.ru
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="adress">  
           </span>
           <p><span class="adress_title">
            Наш адрес:
           </span></p>
           <span class="adress_text">
            <p class="pdng-lft_1">Россия,Омская область,Калачинский<br> район,с.Воскресенка,Пионерская,6</p>
           </span>
          </div> 
        </div>
       </div>
         <div class="map-div">
          <div class="map">
           <script  class="map_script" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3A9e2865ac6578c3a912c97a072fe1e7186b7b7049b91995285666163c39584254&amp;width=47.32vh&amp;height=45vh&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=true"></script>
          </div>
         </div> 
              </div>
         </div>    
     </section>
    </main>
```

Comment: круто - уже youtube вместо кода ... жесть ...код то надо сюда выкладывать

Comment: ох, ё!.. `background-color: rgba(333, 333, 333, .5);`  грустьтоскапечаль...

Comment: @UModeL что-то не так? Я просто учусь.

Comment: @QuickBrownFox значения цвета в RGB могут быть в диапазоне 0-255. Это же основы, но Вы уже целый проект ваяете, не зная их))

Comment: @UModeL практика в бою помогает плотнее выучить материал. Не везде уместно, но тут тоже можно попробовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPD**

У Вас для .text-part-position установлена ширина в 61%. Не знаю, для чего Вам это, но именно потому текст начинается переноситься раньше, чем надо.

---

Оберните номера телефонов в span и задайте им display: inline-block. Они, разумеется, всё равно съедут под ФИО, но целиком - не будут разбиваться на части.

Comment: Сделал, как вы сказали, съехал только один, получается некрасиво: https://ibb.co/QHDyh1K

Comment: но там же ещё полно места до начала карты, можно ли как- нибудь сделать, чтобы она подходила почти вплотную к контактам без перехода на другую строку?

Comment: @QuickBrownFox, а код Вы не хотите добавить в вопрос? как я должен по видео угадывать, почему там место есть, а текст переносится?!

Comment: Извините, не заметил, что произошла ошибка и код не прикрепился..

Comment: @QuickBrownFox, я дополнил ответ